# Keychain functionality for arbitrarily named HTML login form fields?

Tags: html, forms, passwords, keychain

I'm making a secure web login form.
The naming of username and password fields change on each request to prevent automated attacks on these fields.

Form looks like this (simplified):

```
<form><input id="pX3xbdpvgB" type="text"><input id="BxRs1LRpcI7p" type="password"></form>
```

Is there a way to still ensure native browser/OS keychain functionality although the fields aren't named 'login' and 'password' or such?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about the names -- someone trying to automate will not be using the form, and will instead most likely issue the requests directly.

Comment: Added to Sneaky. Web crawlers and injectors are way smarter than just reading the names of the fields. Just validate your I/O correctly and you are fine. CSRF might be a nice addition too.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not concerned about security here. I want to enhance comfort. I want to enable native OS keychain functionality while still having a secure login.